# Writing a Mocha unit test for a function that does not explicitly return a value

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I have a question about writing a Mocha unit test within my Node app when the function doesn't explicitly return anything.

Specifically, the function I want to write a test for iterates over two arrays -- one for inserts and one for updates. That function looks like this:

```
module.exports = async function dataSetsMergeOp(args) {
  const recordsToInsert = args.newRecords;
  const recordsToUpdate = args.matchingRecords;

  // Handle inserts
  if (recordsToInsert.length > 0) {
    for (let record of recordsToInsert) {
      try {
        const insertQuery = `
        INSERT INTO cd.customer_accounts (
          hypindx,
          hypnumbr_1,
          hypnumbr_2,
        ) VALUES (?, ?, ?);
        `;
        const args = [
        record.HYPINDX,
        trimmedStringOrNull(record.HYPNUMBR_1),
        trimmedStringOrNull(record.HYPNUMBR_2),
        ];
        console.log('Record inserting...');
        await queryHandler(insertQuery, args);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
  }

  // Handle updates
  if (recordsToUpdate.length > 0) {
    for (let record of recordsToUpdate) {
      try {
        const updateQuery = `
        UPDATE cd.customer_accounts
        SET
          hypindx = ?,
          hypnumbr_1 = ?,
          hypnumbr_2 = ?
        WHERE hypindx = ?
      `;
      const args = [
        record.ACTINDX,
        trimmedStringOrNull(record.HYPNUMBR_1),
        trimmedStringOrNull(record.HYPNUMBR_2),
        record.HYPINDX
      ];
      console.log('Record updating...');
      await queryHandler(updateQuery, args);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Now the relevant part of my mocha test would look something like this:

```
  before(async function () {
    try {
      result = await dataSetsMergeOp(args);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.stack);
    }
  });
  it("should be truthy", function () {
    assert.isOk(result);
  });
  it("should return an object for the 'job'", function () {
    assert.isObject(result);
  });
  it("should return a number for the 'affectedRows' property", function () {
    assert.typeOf(result.affectedRows, "number");
  });
  it("should return a number for the 'warningStatus' property", function () {
    assert.typeOf(result.warningStatus, "number");
  });
  it("expect 'warningStatus' to be 0", function () {
    expect(result.warningStatus).to.equal(0);
  });
```

But in my case here, because I don't explicitly return anything in the function that's being tested, what `result` ends up being -- even when the function runs successfully -- is `undefined`. And because my function utilizes a `for-of` loop, I don't want to use `return await` in my `dataSetsMergeOp()` function because, while that will make the tests pass, it will stop the loop after the first iteration.

So what's the recommended way to write a test for this kind of function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To **unit test** the function, I would expect that the function throws no exceptions for instance.

You may want to return something like `{ updatedDocumentsCount: n }`, and increment it at every loop iteration, and assert that it equals the number of docs you passed.

For the **integration test**, you want to query your db before and after the function execution, and to check that you actually updated / inserted the expected number of documents.